# Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, connection-string

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58.

I'm using Windows authentication to connect to a SQL Server database from my ASP.NET Core MVC project.

Connection is established successfully, but when I try to login using an existing user, I get this error.

I searched for a different solution like changing authentication mode, enabling TCP/IP and named pipes, restarting the SQL Server services. But nothing works.

Comment: Can you connect via SSMS to the instance with this user?

Comment: The error clearly says it accepts integrated authentication only - so if you try to connect *with an existing user* using user id and password, that'll obviously fail ..... can you show us the **connection string** you're using in your ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: Please include your connnection strings along with server description how are you trying to login and connect from your application.

Comment: You mentioned you changed the authentication mode to allow SQL authentication but did you restart the SQL Server for the change to take effect?

Comment: Your connection string doesn't seem to be configured for Windows authentication/Integrated Security. So where is your ASP.NET Core project running? If it's running in IIS is the Application Pool using an identity that's known to SQL Server, as in due to a [CREATE LOGIN ... FROM WINDOWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql#e-creating-a-login-from-a-windows-domain-account)? If it's running in a *nix server or Docker container, have you joined that to the same domain and, as above, have the Kerberos account known by SQL Server?